# In a struct with a template, why does an lvalue deduce as an rvalue?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue, lvalue, typename

When I call the `g()` function with a `long` variable, why does it call `g(const T& x)`?

If I change `long` to `int`, it calls `g(T& x)` instead.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct s
{
    void g(const T& x) { std::cout << "1\n";}
    void g(T& x) { std::cout << "2\n";}
};

int main() {
    s<int> x;

    long y = 0;
    x.g(y);
}
```

Result:

```
1
```

Comment: You're not calling it with an lvalue.

Comment: There is probably an implicit conversion from `long` to `int` at the call site and thus what is passed is an rvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-const `int&` reference can only bind to an `int` variable and nothing else. `long` and `int` are separate and distinct types, so a `long` variable cannot be assigned to a non-const `int&` reference.  `g(y)` can call `g(int&)` only when `y` is an `int`.

There is an implicit conversion defined from `long` to `int`, and a const reference can bind to a temporary variable. When `y` is `long`, `g(y)` cannot call `g(int&)`, but the compiler can create a temporary `int` variable from the `long` value to call `g(const int&)`.

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying your code to see the error clearly:

```
void g(int& x) { ... }

long y = 0;
g(y);
```

This will result to an error

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of
>   type 'int'

Why?

A *non-const lvalue reference* (i.e. `int&`) will **only** bind to *non-const lvalues* of the same type.

**Only `const` lvalue reference** (i.e. `const int&`) can bind to *rvalue* (which is a temporary object resulting from implicit conversion of `long` to `int`).

Thus,

```
void g(const T& x) { std::cout << "1\n";}
```

will be selected by overload resolution in your given code.

Answer (score 1):

The function call checks for the nearest match for overloaded function.

It checks the type of input argument - in this case long - with any of the existing non-const function calls. g(int&) does not match long, so discarded.

Next it checks the second function g(const int&). This does not match too.

It checks if it could match any one of them by downcasting the input argument. Downcasts y from long to int. As this downcasting produces an rvalue and only const lvalue reference can bind to rvalue g(const int&) is called.

Answer (score 0):

After you specify the template type to be `int`, `T = int` and your functions become `void g(const int& x)` and `void g(int& x)`. Next, compiler will perform template type deduction. Since you pass in `long`, the compiler will attempt to deduce which function fits `long` the "best".

Since `long` is obviously not `int&` and there's no way to convert `long` to `int&`, the compiler "throws" that function away and only the function `g(const int& x)` is left. However, it is possible for `long` to be converted to `int`, which is what the compiler does and because it's an implicit conversion from `long` to `int`, it's an r-value and hence, the function `g(const int& x)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think @codekaizer and @RemyLebeau have given the right answer. You can only bind a rvalue to const lvalue reference. I did a test.

```
#include "print_type.h"
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct s {
  void foo(const T& t) { std::cout << "calling foo(const " << type_name<T>() << "&)\n"; }
  void foo(T& t) { std::cout << "calling foo(" << type_name<T>() << "&)\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
  void bar(const T& t) { std::cout << "calling bar(const " << type_name<T>() << "&)\n"; }

template<typename T>
void bar(T& t) { std::cout << "calling bar(" << type_name<T>() << "&)\n"; }

void g(int& i) { std::cout << "calling g(int&)\n"; }
void g(const int& i) { std::cout << "calling g(const int&)\n"; }

int main() {
  s<int> x;

  int i = 0;
  x.foo(i);
  bar(i);

  const int ci = 0;
  x.foo(ci);
  bar(ci);

  long l = 0;
  x.foo(l);
  bar(l);
  g(l);

  return 0;
}
```

The above code snippet outputs the following result:

```
calling foo(int&)
calling bar(int&)
calling foo(const int&)
calling bar(const int&)
calling foo(const int&)
calling bar(long&)
calling g(const int&)
```

If we don't define function `void g(const int&)`, a error `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'int &' for 1st argument` will be given.